# Youtube iframe embed: force Flash?

Tags: flash, iframe, youtube, embed, html5-video

Is it possible to enforce the flash version of an YouTube video when including it using the new iframe-embed mode?

I don't want the HTML5 version since it is to much hassle for average users (full screen e.g.).

Regards

Comment: Won't YouTube only serve the HTML5 version if the user has opted into the HTML5 Trial?

Comment: No, they're already serving HTML5 videos to all users who have a HTML5 capable browser.

Comment: @Jay are you sure? I get the Flash version when I test the iframe embed in Safari under Mac OS X (like <iframe class="youtube-player" type="text/html" width="640" height="385" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/GuCR_Webyi8" frameborder="0"></iframe>)

Comment: Thats right. Youtube hasn't encoded all videos as H.264/WebM/Theora yet. Therefore some videos are delivered as classic flash and some as HTML5 (depending on client capabilities). You can try this one http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=a6cNdhOKwi0 for instance, it's avaible as HTML5.

Comment: Yes, you are right, that one gives me the HTML5 version, in an iframe and at youtube.com, although I'm not in the "trial".

Comment: After silently dropping flash 'fallback' support for youtube's site on 27 July 2017 (https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/youtube/CUaTWvKhAuE), *today* they also killed flash-embedded video's (as per usual without any word/warning/press-release). A flash-embedded youtube video shows the text: **"Flash-embedded videos are no longer supported, but you can still watch this video on YouTube."** Sadly this the final nail in the proverbial coffin: no viable workarounds (including browser-plugins) are left to use/force flash as of today. `:(`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm fairly confident the iframe option does not include a parameter to select html5 or flash as iframe is to allow youtube to change their code in the future.

If you absolutely want flash, just use the old youtube embed code (instead of the new iframe): http://www.tools4noobs.com/online_tools/youtube_xhtml/

That will still work and deliver the flash version 100% of the time :)

And If you still want to use both, add in some simple browser detection. Serve the flash embed code to the problem clients, iframe to everyone else.

Comment: You can create a flash player with the iframe,check my answer below.

Comment: *As of today **0% of the time**...* After silently dropping flash 'fallback' support for youtube's site on 27 July 2017 (https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/youtube/CUaTWvKhAuE), *today* they also killed flash-embedded video's (as per usual without any word/warning/press-release). A flash-embedded youtube video shows the text: **"Flash-embedded videos are no longer supported, but you can still watch this video on YouTube."** Sadly this the final nail in the proverbial coffin: no viable workarounds (including browser-plugins) are left to use/force flash as of today. `:(`

Answer (score 3):

You can create youtube flash player embed code in any of the two ways given below.

**Method 1**

Here are the iframe code for both players.

**HTML5 player**

```
<iframe width="350" height="150" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/ffiJNSy8CBA"><iframe>
```

**Flash version**

```
<iframe width="350" height="150" src="https://www.youtube.com/v/ffiJNSy8CBA"><iframe>
```

Notice the difference? Simply change the `/embed/` to `/v/`

Here is a [youtube embed code generator tool](http://codegena.com/generator/Youtube-Embed-Code-Generator.html) with which you can customize the youtube embed player.

**Method 2**

This is a far simple method to load flash player. You can use the `&nohtml5=1` parameter to load flash version of that video.

Example url : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wAN77SmbKBY&nohtml5=1